# How to convert bytes to ndarray in python 3 using numpy.ndarray.toString() and numpy.fromString()?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, byte, lmdb

In order to save in lmdb , I use numpy.ndarray.toString() to convert an ndarray to a bytes object,and when I want to read the bytes to an ndarray with numpy.fromString(),I get an ndarray but the shape changed.So how to convert between them?

I have tried to use pickle with dumps() and loads(),but there was some exception in

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '?'.
```

save code here :

```py
class face_lmdb:
    def add_embed_to_lmdb(self,id,vector):
        self.db_file=os.path.abspath(face_comm.get_conf('lmdb','lmdb_path'))
        id = str(id)
        evn = lmdb.open(self.db_file)
        wfp = evn.begin(write=True)
        print(vector.shape)# here is (512,)
        wfp.put(key=id.encode(), value=vector.toString())
        wfp.commit()
        evn.close()
```

load code here

```py
    def create_index_from_lmdb(self):
        lmdb_file = self.lmdb_file
        if os.path.isdir(lmdb_file):
            evn = lmdb.open(lmdb_file)
            wfp = evn.begin()
            annoy = AnnoyIndex(self.f)
            for key, value in wfp.cursor():
                key = int(key)
                print(type(value))#here is bytes
                value = np.fromstring(value)
                print(value.shape)# here is (256,)
                annoy.add_item(key,value)

            annoy.build(self.num_trees)
            annoy.save(self.annoy_index_path)
```

I expect the shape is `(512,)`,butI get `(256,)`

Comment: Might be a matter of matching `dtype`s. (Make sure they are the same before saving and after loading.)

Comment: I look up the doc of ndarray ,aboutthe type ,`float`  is the default type,and I tried `int`,but didn't work either

Comment: You must use the exact same `dtype` as in `vector`. You can query that using `vector.dtype`.

Comment: Yes,you are right ! I find out that  they are in different type.